# access django fk related objects in view as template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a **models** as

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
           User,
           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
           primary_key=True,
           related_name="user")

    # other fields...
```

In my `template`, I easily can access the doctor object as `request.user.doctor` but using it in my `views` it causes the `'User' object has no attribute 'doctor'` Error. so is it possible to access it as **templates** in my **views** too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so to access the `Doctor` object from a `User`, since you have set this to `user`, you thus access the `Doctor` object with `request.user.user`, but that is misleading.

You thus better rename the relation to:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='doctor'
    )
    # other fields …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: oh god! Thankkk you so much sir :) yeah thats it.